# Xcode target and multiple implementations of same header

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Working with somebody else's code, I am re-writing implementation (.m file) for an existing interface (.h).

I see some lines like
   `NSURL *playbackURL = [[self.currentPlaybackURL retain] autorelease];`

My new class is giving me errors. Which should be legit because now we have ARC. Probably wasn't there when earlier file was written. Could somebody help me why earlier implementation not giving these errors?

The tricky part here is my new implementation here is for a new target. Both .m files are for individual targets.

But.. The new target is just a duplicate of existing one.

Now what should I do about ARC, should I just change code lines like above to something like:

```
NSURL *playbackURL = self.currentPlaybackURL;
```

Or are there any better ways in Xcode to handle cases like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you copied your target, you might have copied the **-fno-objc-arc** flags on the (.m file). Please make sure that your new target doesn't have those flags for those (.m files).

You may find those by checking out in **build phases** >> **Compile Sources**

Comment: Where do I look for it ?

Comment: No not yet Vasanth, give me some time to test. I got busy onto another problem. But I see your point. I will +1 your answer. Will mark answer after I test it. Thanks.